How to combine list of objects into list of tuples (matrix style) in Python?
Let's say that I have a list of tuples foo (object, integer) and a list of objects bar.  The length of each of these parent lists is variable. How do I combine them into a single list of tuples, wherein each tuple is a unique combination of elements from each of the two parent lists?

Example 1:
foo = [(A, i)]
bar = [X, Y]
# missing magic
expected_result = [(A, i, X), (A, i, Y)]


Example 2:
foo = [(A, i), (B, j)]
bar = [X, Y]
# missing magic
expected_result = [(A, i, X), (A, i, Y), (B, j, X), (B, j, Y)]


Example 3:
foo = [(A, i), (B, j), (C, k)]
bar = [X, Y]
# missing magic
expected_result = [(A, i, X), (A, i, Y), (B, j, X), (B, j, Y), (C, k, X), (C, k, Y)]


Example 4:
foo = [(A, i), (B, j)]
bar = [X]
# missing magic
expected_result = [(A, i, X), (B, j, X)]



Preferably, I'd like to do this in one line, if possible. The order of the resulting list is unimportant, but the order of the elements within the tuples of that list need to be predictable.
In addition to trying various solutions using itertools.product and zip, I also looked at the answers to other similar questions, but I was unable to find the solution to this problem.

It seems like itertools.product is exactly what you want, or even just a for loop in a for loop - please give a [mre] rather than a vague description.

@jonrsharpe It doesn't do exactly what OP wants, because it would return a list of tuples, each having a tuple and an element. Also, 4 examples looks like a good MCVE, since OP doesn't have a bug but rather a question about how to do it correctly.

@Gugu72 those are requirements; a [mre] includes what you tried and what the actual outcome was, this isn't a code-writing service. And yes product (and the loops you've suggested as an answer) would give e.g. ((A, i), X), but then surely it's trivial to find out how to get one tuple from that (or that would be the question they'd ask, if it wasn't already here)? Hence again I want to know what their actual problem is.

I wouldn't say unpacking is trivial, and even though trivial, it doesn't answer OP's question. Using itertools.product is not an answer to the question.

It's truly unfortunate that the Stack Overflow community has become so unfriendly.  It's no wonder that it has lost popularity and gone down in the search rankings.  I remember a time when SO used to be the first result of any programming related Google search.  No longer...so sad. :'(

Your case is indeed tricky, and zip or itertools.product do not directly do the job, since you want to concatenate a tuple and an element into a tuple with all elements.
In one line, you can use unpacking:
expected_result = [(*i, j) for i in foo for j in bar]

Assuming, as in your example, that foo is a list of tuples and bar is a list of elements.

itertools.product does exactly the job your two for loops do, it's not tricky.

@jonrsharpe why do not you suggest your answer ?

@jonrsharpe It doesn't do exactly that, because it doesn't do the unpacking. Using itertools.product, you get something like [((A, i), X), ((A, i), Y), ...].

Because the OP claimed they tried that and it didn't work, so I want to understand what their actual problem is. And I said it does the same thing as the loops, after which you can do exactly the same unpacking.

You can use a list comprehension with nested loops, spreading the elements in foo:
[(*f, b) for f in foo for b in bar]

